# Firebase send notifications when new record added to database

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3

I'm working on an IONIC 3 app with firebase,
this app is used by agents/admins.
agents : send their locations data (latitude, longitude, etc..) to the firebase database.
admins: just manage the agents accounts and check their data ...

=> briefly I just want to send a push notifications to the admins accounts when a new record is added to AGENTS-GPS-COORDS (picture below).
Is that possible ? if it is how to do it ?
ps: I'm not using Firebase Admin SDK.

thanks in advance :)

[image]

Comment: Look into Cloud Functions for Firebase to perform some work on the server side in response to changes in your database. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Comment: Look up tutorial by Jeff at AngularFirebase. It is in angular but you can modify it to meet your needs https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/send-push-notifications-in-angular-with-firebase-cloud-messaging/

Comment: thanks so much @Abdul-RazakAdam this is exactly what I need, but I couldn't change it to make it work with my RTDB instead of Firestore. can you help me about this ? thanks again